# Retrieving more than 1000 records from azure storage table - js

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have an issue of retrieving more than a thousand records. Somehow only the first 1000 are retrieved. From my research, I have figured out that I have to use getContinuation Token to get the subsequent records. Please advise how should I add it into my code.

```
tableService.queryEntities(table, tableQuery, null, function(error, results) {
    if (error) {
        alert('List table entities error, please open browser console to view detailed error');
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        //display records

});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure table storage continuation tokens in Node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47786874/azure-table-storage-continuation-tokens-in-node-js)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To work with callback based on your code, use recursion.

```
var entities = [];
function queryEntitiesSegmented(table, tableQuery, continuationToken){
    tableService.queryEntities(table, tableQuery, continuationToken, (error, results)=> {
        if (error) {   console.log(error); } 
        else { 
            entities.push.apply(entities, results.entries);
            if(results.continuationToken){
                queryEntitiesSegmented(table, tableQuery, results.continuationToken);
            }
            else{
                entities.forEach(entity=>{
                   // display each one
                })
            }
        }
    });
}

queryEntitiesSegmented(table, tableQuery, null);
```

Another choice is async and await.

```
const queryEntitiesSegmented = async(table, tableQuery, continuationToken)=>{
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        tableService.queryEntities(table, tableQuery, continuationToken, (error, results)=> {
            if (error) {  reject(error); } 
            else { resolve(results);  }
        });
    });
}

async function queryAllEntities(){
    var tableQuery = new azure.TableQuery();
    var table = 'tableName';
    var continuationToken = null;
    var entities = [];
    do{
        var results =  await queryEntitiesSegmented(table, tableQuery, continuationToken);
        continuationToken = results.continuationToken;
        entities.push.apply(entities, results.entries);
    }
    while(continuationToken!=null);
    return entities;
}

queryAllEntities().then(entities=>{
    entities.forEach(entity=>{
    //display each one
    })
}).catch(error=>{ console.log(error); })
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works in C#:

```cs
var resultList = new List<T>();
TableQuery<T> query = new TableQuery<T>();

TableContinuationToken continuationToken = null;


var table = _tableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);

do
{
    var token = continuationToken;
    var queryResult = TryOperation(() => table.ExecuteQuerySegmented(new TableQuery<T>(), token), tableName);
    if (queryResult != null)
    {
        resultList.AddRange(queryResult.Results);
        continuationToken = queryResult.ContinuationToken;
    }
} while (continuationToken != null);

return resultList;
```

Comment: The question is looking for a solution in Node while your answer is in .Net.

Answer (score 0):

I created an npm package just for this if you want to use it.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-table-query-recursive

Usage

```
const {queryAzureTableStorage, TableQuery, createTableService} = require('azure-table-query-recursive');

const validConnectionString = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxxxxxx;AccountKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net';
const query = `PartitionKey eq 'apartitionkey'`;
const table = 'aTable';

//Constract a tableStorage object
const tableStorage = createTableService(validConnectionString);
//Constract an azure table query
const azureQuery = new TableQuery().where(query);

const tableResults = await queryAzureTableStorage(azureQuery, table, tableStorage);
```